# Imported Texture only on one side of Object

Tags: texturing, uv

I am new to Blender and have started making a teddy bear from Blender Guru on YT.

I downloaded the texture for the wool needed from the video, but the wool texture is only displayed on the front side of the teddy bear, instead of the whole teddy bear.

I am not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Can you check your node tree and look for the image texture - see if it is connected to a texture coordinate node, and if it is using UV mapping.

Comment: I have the texture node(UV) connect to the mapping(vector) with is connected to the png of the texture(vector) which is connected to the displacement(height).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Solved the problem by unwrapping the back half of the mesh(the part were their is no texture), which is when the texture applied to the half that it was not before!